# How to use PayPal for checkout in rails4

Tags: paypal, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am trying to add PayPal e-paiement to my RoR application. so I proceed as follow:
My panier.rb:

```
class Panier < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user



 def paypal_url(return_path)
values = {
    :business => 'r.karoui-buyer@loganddrive.com',
    :cmd => '_cart',
    :upload => 1,
    :return => return_path,
    :invoice => id
}
line_items.each_with_index do |item, index|
  values.merge!({
                    "amount_#{index+1}" => item.price,
                    "item_name_#{index+1}" => item.book.title,
                    "item_number_#{index+1}" => item.id,
                    "quantity_#{index+1}" => 1
                })
  end

 "#{Rails.application.secrets.paypal_host}/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
end
end
```

my details.html.erb: where i call the PayPal service

```
<%= @panier.book_id %> | <%= @panier.price %> | <%= link_to 'acheter' , @panier.paypal_url(paniers_path) %>
```

but I got this error:

> undefined local variable or method `line_items' for #

i just follow this railsCast tutorial :

> http://railscasts.com/episodes/141-paypal-basics

what should I put in place of line_items.each_with_index do |item, index| if it is here the errors if not please help me to find out where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
def paypal_url(return_path)
values = {
    :business => 'r.karoui-buyer@loganddrive.com',
    :cmd => '_cart',
    :upload => 1,
    :return => return_path,
    :invoice => id
}

 values.merge!({
                "amount_#{index+1}" => item.price,
                "item_name_#{index+1}" => item.book.title,
                "item_number_#{index+1}" => item.id,
                "quantity_#{index+1}" => 1
            })


 "#{Rails.application.secrets.paypal_host}/cgi-bin/webscr?" + values.to_query
end
```